Isomorphism between $\mathcal{L} ( \mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2 )$ and $ \mathcal{L} ( \mathcal{H}_1 ) \otimes \mathcal{L} ( \mathcal{H}_2 )$.
Let $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ be two separable Hilbert spaces.
Let $\mathcal{L} ( \mathcal{H} )$ be the $C^*$ - algebra of bounded linear operators on $\mathcal{H}$, a separable Hilbert space.
How to show that, $\mathcal{L} ( \mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2 ) \simeq \mathcal{L} ( \mathcal{H}_1 ) \otimes \mathcal{L} ( \mathcal{H}_2 )$ ( Isomorphism of $C^*$ - algebras ) ?
Thanks in advance for your help.

I'm by no means an expert in functional analysis, so pardon the dumb question. Did you try just doing the same thing as in the proof for finite dimensional vector spaces? People generally appreciate when you include your own efforts, and this seems a natural thing to try. I guess the main sticking point is with the tensor product completion?

Thank you, but, in the expression, $ \mathcal{L} ( \mathcal{H}_1 ) \otimes \mathcal{L} ( \mathcal{H}_2 ) $, which kind of tensor product $ \otimes $ of $ C^*$ - algebras is concerned by this isomorphism which we should establish ?

This is well-known to be not true unless the dimension of at least one of the Hilbert spaces is finite, if the tensor product on the RHS is interpreted as any $C^\ast$-algebraic tensor product. One easy way to see this is that the LHS has only one nonzero proper ideal, namely the compact operators, whereas the RHS has at least three, namely $K(H_1) \otimes B(H_2)$, $B(H_1) \otimes K(H_2)$, and $K(H_1) \otimes K(H_2)$.

The correct statement would have been if the tensor product on the RHS is understood as the von Neumann algebra tensor product instead of any $C^\ast$-algebraic tensor product. In that case you basically don’t need any proof for this. It’s practically just the definition of von Neumann algebra tensor products.

Thank you for this comment Sir. :-)

$\def\l{\mathcal L}\def\h{\mathcal H}$The question is phrased in an inconsistent way, for when $\h_1$ and $\h_2$ are infinite-dimensional there exists more than one (uncountably many if I'm not wrong) distinct tensor products between $\l(\h_1)$ and $\l(\h_2)$. See here for some information on this.
The natural thing here is to take the spatial product, but one needs the tensor product as von Neumann algebras. Which amount to consider $\l(\h_1)\odot\l(\h_2)\subset\l(\h_1\otimes\h_2)$ and take the closure in the weak or strong operator topology. So one defines
$$
\l(\h_1)\otimes\l(\h_2):=\overline{\l(\h_1)\odot\l(h_2)}^{\rm sot}= [{\l(\h_1)\odot\l(h_2)}]''.
$$
So we want to show that $[{\l(\h_1)\odot\l(h_2)}]''=\l(\h_1\otimes\h_2)$. Suppose that $T\in\l(\h_1\otimes\h_2)$ commutes with every element of ${\l(\h_1)\odot\l(h_2)}$. Given an elementary tensor $\xi\otimes\eta\in\h_1\otimes\h_2$, let $P_{\xi\otimes\eta}$ be the orthogonal projection onto $\mathbb C\,(\xi\otimes\eta)$. We have $$
T(\xi\otimes\eta)=TP_{\xi\otimes\eta}(\xi\otimes\eta)=P_{\xi\otimes\eta}T(\xi\otimes\eta)=\lambda_{\xi\otimes\eta}\,(\xi\otimes\eta)
$$
for a uniquely defined $\lambda_{\xi\otimes\eta}\in\mathbb C$. Given nonzero $\xi'\in\h_1$, $\eta'\in\h_2$, let $S$ be the rank-one operator that maps $\xi\otimes\eta$ to $\xi'\otimes\eta'$. Then, if $T(\xi\otimes\eta)\ne0$,
\begin{align}
\xi'\otimes\eta'&=S(\xi\otimes\eta)
=\lambda_{\xi\otimes\eta}^{-1}ST(\xi\otimes\eta)
=\lambda_{\xi\otimes\eta}^{-1}TS(\xi\otimes\eta)\\[0.2cm]
&=\lambda_{\xi\otimes\eta}^{-1}T(\xi'\otimes\eta')
=\lambda_{\xi\otimes\eta}^{-1}\lambda_{\xi'\otimes\eta'}\,(\xi'\otimes\eta').
\end{align}
Thus $\lambda_{\xi\otimes\eta}=\lambda{\xi'\otimes\eta'}$. In other words, $T=\lambda I$. This proves that $\l(\h_1)\odot\l(h_2)$ has trivial commutant, and hence
$$
[{\l(\h_1)\odot\l(h_2)}]''=\l(\h_1\otimes\h_2). 
$$

Thank you very much Sir. :-) Neverthless, what is the meaning of ''sot'' in $ \overline{\l(\h_1)\odot\l(\h_2)}^{\rm sot} $ ?

"Strong operator topology".

Thank you Sir.  :-)

Indeed, there are undoubtably many tensor norms on $B(l^2) \otimes B(l^2)$, a result first proved by Ozawa and Pisier in “A continuum of $C^\ast$-norms on $B(H) \otimes B(H)$ and related tensor products”. That there are at least two was first proved by Junge and Pisier in “Bilinear forms on exact operator spaces and $B(H) \otimes B(H)$”. (On a side note, even the second result is not just because $B(H)$ is not nuclear. For example, there is only one tensor norm on $C^\ast(\mathbb{F}_\infty) \otimes B(l^2)$, despite neither tensor components being nuclear.)

(You can even have $A \otimes A$ having only one tensor norm despite $A$ being non-nuclear, see this paper of Pisier.)

Nice. I remembered Junge-Pisier, but was barely aware of Ozawa-Pisier. And I didn't know at all about Pisier's paper, that sounds awesome.

(A small correction: in my first comment I meant “uncountably many” tensor norms instead of “undoubtedly many”. It seems autocorrect has made an error again.)
